# Check if wordpress user meta key exists before outputting html

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a Wordpress user query that is echoing out a bunch of information from a list of users in a custom role. Everything is working properly, but I'm trying to prepare for a very probable outcome. The code starts below:

```
$args = array(
    'role' => 'BBCDirectory',
    'search' => ''
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<div class="singleperson">'
         . '<div style="margin:50px 0; height:1px; line-height:1px; background:#CCCCCC;"></div><span class="bbcavatar" style="float:left; margin:0 20px 20px 0;"><a href="' . get_author_posts_url($user->ID) . '"><img src="' . get_author_image_url( $user->ID ) . '" alt="" /></a></span>'
         . '<h3 class="bbcname"><a href="' . get_author_posts_url($user->ID) . '">' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</a></h3>'
         . '<span class="bbclocation"><em>' . esc_html( $user->bbccity ) . ', ' . esc_html( $user->bbcstate ) . '</em></span>'
         . '<span class="bbcabout"><strong style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.25em;">About Me</strong><br />' . esc_textarea( $user->bbcabout ) . '</span>'
         . '<span class="bbcclassschedule"><strong style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.25em;">My Class Schedule</strong><br />' . esc_html( $user->bbcclassschedule ) . '</span>'
         . '<span class="contactheader"><strong style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.25em;">Contact ' . esc_html( $user->first_name ) . '</strong><br />'
         . '<span class="bbcwebsite"><a target="_blank" href="' . esc_html( $user->bbcwebsite ) . '"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></i></a></span>'
         . '<span class="bbcemail"><a href="mailto:' . esc_html( $user->bbcemail ) . '"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></a></span>'
         . '<span class="bbcfacebook"><a target="_blank" href="' . esc_html( $user->bbcfacebook ) . '"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></span>'
         . '<span class="bbctwitter"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/' . esc_html( $user->bbctwitter ) . '"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></span>'
         . '<span class="bbcphone"><a id="bbcphone" href="#null"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i></a><span class="bbcphonenumber">' . esc_html( $user->bbcphone ) . '</span></span>'
         . '</div>'
         ;
    }
```

So this pulls up all kinds of things – email addresses, websites, social media profiles, etc. What I'm wanting to do is actually test to make sure those things are in the database, and if they aren't...don't try to echo that part. For example, if they don't have a Facebook page, don't echo the line starting with

```
         . '<span class="bbcfacebook"><a target="_blank" href="' . esc_html( $user->bbcfacebook ) . '"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></span>'
```

Seems pretty straightforward, but the way I'm echoing out the content isn't perhaps the most conducive to conditional statements. Maybe I should try that query a different way?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Outside of your loop define variable `$return;`. Then add your div contents like `$return .= '<div class="singleperson">';` and before any info that can be empty preform an `if()` check to see if it's empty or not. If it is, in the if loop you'll put `$return .= 'your content here';` and so on, and at the end, just `return` ( or `echo`) that variable.

Comment: Would that apply to the whole thing? Or specific lines? As it stands now, it will return every line, or no lines. I want it to skip the lines that don't exist. Forgive my inexperience with php...I'm figuring this out as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it like this

```
// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$return = '';

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {

        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $display_name = $user->display_name;
        $location = isset($user->bbcstate) && isset($user->bbccity);
        $about = $user->bbcabout;
        $schedule = $user->bbcclassschedule;
        $user_name = $user->first_name;
        $website = $user->bbcwebsite;
        $email = $user->bbcemail;
        $facebook = $user->bbcfacebook;
        $twitter = $user->bbctwitter;
        $phone = $user->bbcphone;

        $return .= '<div class="singleperson">
                    <div style="margin:50px 0; height:1px; line-height:1px; background:#CCCCCC;">/div>';
        if ($user_id != '') {
            $return .= '<span class="bbcavatar" style="float:left; margin:0 20px 20px 0;"><a href="' . get_author_posts_url($user->ID) . '"><img src="' . get_author_image_url( $user->ID ) . '" alt="" /></a></span>';
        }
        if ($display_name != '') {
            $return .= '<h3 class="bbcname"><a href="' . get_author_posts_url($user->ID) . '">' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</a></h3>';
        }

        ...

        $return .= '</div>';
    }

    return $return; // or echo $return;
}
```

Just fill in the if's :)

Comment: Ok. Yeah...this is definitely doing what I asked, but it's also doing something strange. I have three "users". Before changing the query...it would post them as Anna, Jane, and Sarah. Now it's returning Anna, Anna, Jane, Anna, Jane, Sarah. Any ideas on the duplicates?

Comment: Oh, try putting the `return $return` (or `echo`) outside of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Ah, yeah, brilliant. That worked. That was throwing me for a loop. #stupidpun. Hey, cheers! Appreciate the help. Just what I needed.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) Just a tip, the `$location` one will give you a boolean (`true` or `false`), so its `if` statement is `if($location){...}`. Just a `true/false` check :) The rest are to see if there is something inside :)